# Login screen shows wrong battery percentage

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, mojave

My 2018 Macbook Pro 13 login screen shows 96% and shows no charging indicator even though the power is connected. When I log in it shows 100% and the charging/power indicator.

I am running Mojave 10.14.1. The Macbook is only a few days old. There is no other issue with the battery or charging.

I tried resetting the SMC but not sure if it worked. Is there a way to tell? It did not fix the wrong battery display.

Could it be in some way connected that I restored the system from a timemachine backup that came from a different Macbook model? The system also refused to shut down twice now. And this too I have not experienced with any other Macbook before.